# SQL get variable in middle of string

Tags: sql-server-2008, substring, audit

I am attempting to create my first SQL Audit and I've ran into a bit of a snag.  I have two tables, a temp table that has the Audit log, and a table with Lastnames (lets call it tblLastName).

Now, the audit is against anything with a SELECT against specific tables and I want to take the results and compare them with my Last Name table.  Basically, in the Audit table is the statement column, in there will be something similar to

```
where lastname like %personslastname%
```

How might I go about getting just the value between the % % to compare it against the lastnames table.

At the moment I can get which rows have a last name selected against, but I do not know how to turn that into anything useful.  My logic I thought would work would be to get the rows that have a last name, get the substring (which is where i am stuck) of that row to get just the name, store that name in a variable, and then compare against the other table.  Unfortunately all I have so far is:

```
select * from #MyTempTable where statement like '%LastName like%'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Also it is SQL Server 2008.

Edit for data:

```
SELECT vLastName from tblLastName
```

produces results like:
Super User,
Hendrix,
Greenwood,
Page,

My Audit Statement is much more in depth though so I've taken a bit out:

```
select DISTINCT 
  x.ReceiveMail as [Receive Mail], 
  x.ParticipantID as [Participant ID], 
  x.LastName as [Last Name], 
  x.FirstName as [First Name], 
  x.AliasName as [Alias Name], ......  
where x.LastName like '%Greenwood%' 
AND (x.FirstName like '%Jonny%' OR x.AliasName like '%Jonny%')
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: Can you provide sample data of AuditTable.StatementColumn too?

Comment: Sorry SQLChao for not being clear, the above audit statement is the text that was inside the statement column.  I have a few hundred rows of similar strings that are saved when a select query is run.

Comment: Is there a possibility of a malformed where statement?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I maybe wasn't clear, I am attempting to take the last name out of the audit results, so in the above example, take 'Greenwood' out and compare it against a list of known last names.
So I have a statement now that attempts to get the charindex before and after that string but it wont work.

Comment: Are you looking for this?: `declare @LastName varchar(30) = 'Greenwood'; select ... where x.LastName like '%' + @LastName + '%'`